# How to publish a Russian edition of a book on Amazon?

Tags: publishing, amazon

How can I publish a Russian book on Amazon? I have found many books in Russian but could not find any way to publish my Russian edition.

Answer (score 1):

According to their documentation ([Book Supported Languages](https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/G200673300)), it's not supported by Kindle to publish in Russian.

For further information I would recommend reaching out to Amazon to find out if they have some non-standard way of publishing in a language not on the list, or what your options are.

Answer (score 0):

Now, Amazon (KDP) allows you to choose the Ukrainian language in the paperback details. So, you may try to add your Russian book as Ukrainian. I would suggest adding something like "русское издание" as a subtitle to avoid confusing people.

Alternatively, you can do this thru Global Distribution on lulu.com, but printing costs will be higher.

Comment: Have you tried publishing in "Ukrainian" like that? The link in the other answer says "Select the language in your Bookshelf that matches the language of the written content to prevent file rejection." so it seems like this wouldn't work.

Comment: @Laurel I said "you may try", but I saw some Russian books on amazon that marked as Ukrainian.